# Prolog - equal operator wrapping

Tags: prolog, equals

```
equal(a, b) :- (a = b).
```

I defined equal.

```sh
1 ?- [index].
true.

2 ?- equal(1, 1).
false.

3 ?- 1 = 1.
true.
```

When I run

```
equal(1, 1)
```

it returns false.

Why does it return false and how can i fix it?

Comment: Variables in prolog must start with an Uppercase. Try `equal(A, B) :- (A = B).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should write  `equal(A, B) :- A = B` instead of what you've written. The difference is that a and b are constants and A and B are variables that can be unified with values. I guess then it should work for your example.

But you should note that "=" predicate just tries to unify its arguments. So when you ask "1 = 1" the result is true because 1 unifies with 1. But when you ask "2 + 2 = 4" (or equal(2 + 2, 4)) the result will be false because this operator does not evaluate arithmetic operations. If comparing arithmetic expressions is what you want to do use =:= operator instead:

`equal(A, B) :- A =:= B`.